# How to use Checkbox with Array of Text View to add the word to Favorites

Tags: java, android, android-checkbox

Hallow:
I am a beginner in Android Studio. I have created an app with an Array of words when the user press the next button the next word will display in the text view but my problem is:
how to use checkbox with Array of words so that when user check it, the word in text view will be added to the favorite. I think i need to create an Array of check Boxes, but how to put multiple check Boxes in one place and how to move between items?.

Thank you for your help.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/580OQ.jpg)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

private Button nextButton;
private Button prevButton;
private TextView wordTextView;
private CheckBox mcheckbox1;
private ArrayList<String> texts = new ArrayList<>();
private int index =0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    nextButton = findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
    prevButton = findViewById(R.id.prevButton);
    wordTextView = findViewById(R.id.wordTextView);
    mcheckbox1 = findViewById(R.id.mcheckbox1);

    setTextsContains();

    nextButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    prevButton.setOnClickListener(this);

}

private void setTextsContains ( ){


    texts.add("Apple");
    texts.add("Banana");
    texts.add("Earth");
    texts.add("Man");
    texts.add("Woman");

    wordTextView.setText(texts.get(index));

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    int id = v.getId();

    if (id == R.id.nextButton ){
        index++;

    }else if (id == R.id.prevButton){
        index--;
    }
    setTextsContains();
}
```

}